# React-Bootstrap & end-aligned nav menus w/ .dropdown-menu-end

Tags: react-bootstrap

I'm working with react-bootstrap 2.3.0, have a fixed navbar with a few NavDropdowns and have them all aligned right. I need to apply the class `dropdown-menu-end` to the last Dropdown div, but the `NavDropdown` component covers the entirety of the nav item and the dropdown menu.

The top div with the class applied is what the `NavDropdown` component renders, but the blue selected div is where the class needs to be.

Is there a way to get this class applied in React Bootstrap?

```
<Nav ... >

<NavDropdown title="Tools & Calculators" id="navbarToolsAndCalcsDropdown" className={"dropdown-menu-end"}>
    <Button as={NavDropdown.Item} onClick={this.handleThing}>thing</Button>
    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action">Other Link</NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>

</Nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On *Dropdown.Menu* component there is a property called *align*, you have to set it to *end*:

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/#dropdown-menu-props

The reason why you don't see your dropdown menu aligning right is the fact, that the class *dropdown-menu* is given a *min-width* of *10rem*. When you want to remove the min-width, target bootstrap class in css either directly or create your own class and target the dropdown menu div:

```
.dropdownMenu div {
  min-width: 0rem;
}
```

I created a sandbox where I demonstrate this behaviour:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-cherry-uedct

[image]

Comment: So, I'm using NavDropdown, not Dropdown.Menu which was my confusion. Turns out though that NavDropdown _also_ has an align prop, it's just not in the docs! https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/navs/#nav-dropdown-props